# problems with url and email regex when searching text

Tags: php, regex

I'm having problems with regular expressions that I got from regexlib.  I am trying to do a preg_replace() on a some text and want to replace/remove email addresses and URLs (http/https/ftp).

The code that I am have is:

```
$sanitiseRegex = array(
    'email' => /'^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/',
    'http' => '/^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$/',        
);

$replace = array(
    'xxxxx',
    'xxxxx'
);

$sanitisedText = preg_replace($sanitiseRegex, $replace, $text);
```

However I am getting the following error: **Unknown modifier '/'** and **$sanitisedText** is null.

Can anyone see the problem with what I am doing or why the regex is failing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, your email string is opened incorrectly:

```
'email' => /'^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.
// should be
'email' => '/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.
```

The other problem is that you are using `/` as a character to match and using it the start/end your URL regex, without escaping them in the regex. The simplest solution to simply use a different character to denote start/end of the regex, ie:

```
'http' => '@^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$@'
```

What is happening is that it sees `'^(http|https|ftp)\:'` as the regex, then starts looking for options. The first character after the 'end' of the regex is another `'/'` which is an invalid option, hence the error message.

**EDIT:** Something quick that might fix the issue re: not matching. You could try the following instead:

```
'http' => '@^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?(/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~]*)?$@'
```

Comment: thanks the first one I should of spotted.. however the second looking for the url using the http regex fails to find http://www.google.com ?

Comment: Then it's an issue with your regex. It's too complicated for me to dig into, but that's where the issue lies.

Comment: Fixed it another typo... need sleep.  Thanks again Matthew